# react create app console will not output anything

Tags: reactjs

i'm using react create app. ejected project.

When I console.log('hello') in the home component, nothing output. And it seem the server restart every time I save somethig.

This is my component

```js
import React from 'react';

    const css = {
    }

    export default function Home(props) {
        console.log('hello')
        return (
            <div> something</div>
        )
    }
```

This is what the console shows every-time I save some change. it does nothing. I expect it show 'hello in the console'

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to open `http://localhost:3000` in your browser, after that open your browser devtools and select `console` tab, there you will see the console output.